# Checking if a BroadcastReceiver is declared in the manifest in runtime?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

Is there a way to check which BroadcastReceivers are declared in the manifest, in runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, but was not my intention... I wanted to get know if a specific receiver is declared in the running application in runtime, and achieved it like this:

```
    private <Receiver extends CyborgReceiver<?>> boolean checkIfBroadcastReceiverIsRegisteredInManifest(Class<Receiver> receiverType) {
    PackageManager pm = application.getPackageManager();
    try {
        ActivityInfo info = pm.getReceiverInfo(new ComponentName(application, receiverType), PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS);
        return info.enabled;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: CyborgReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver, and regarding the filters, I really don't remember the case.

Comment: I think it had something to do with monitoring the call events in the application.

Answer (score 3):

With `PackageManager`, you can `queryBroadcastReceivers()` to find who will all respond to a specific `Intent`, and with `getInstalledPackages()`, you can find out the receivers installed per package.

Answer (score 3):

The code would be similar like this, from within an Activity:

```
// Query all packages that have the BroadcastReceivers...
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> listPkgs = pm.queryBroadcast(mainIntent, 0);
if (listPkgs != null && listPkgs.size() > 0){
   for(ResolveInfo resInfo : listPkgs){
       // Now resInfo will contain the list of packages that has receivers...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the application object as the first argument, you can do this with `(Application)context.GetApplicationContext()` if you have to, then pass in your  class which implements the broadcast receiver class as the second argument e.g. `broadcastReceiver.class`

```
public static boolean validateReceiverInManifest(Application application, Class receiverClass) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    PackageManager pm = application.getPackageManager();
    String packageName = application.getPackageName();

    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS);
    ActivityInfo[] receivers = packageInfo.receivers;
    String receiverClassName = receiverClass.getName();
    for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : receivers) {
        if (activityInfo.name.equals(receiverClassName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```